# How can I change a file type's default program while keeping its current default icon on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, icons, file-types

Let's say I want to open XML files in Notepad, I can change the default program through Control Panel > Programs > Default Programs > Associate a file type or protocol with a program.

However, that will also change its default icon to that of a text file. If I repeat the process for other file types then I lose the ability to easily distinguish different files in a folder based on their icon.

So after I change the default program, I would like to 'roll back' the icon change.

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xmlfile\DefaultIcon` stays the same as before the default program changed: `%SystemRoot%\System32\msxml3.dll,0`

I tried adding `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\xmlfile\DefaultIcon`, as well as `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.xml\DefaultIcon` but neither seem to work.

What registry key(s) should I change to get back the old icon (`%SystemRoot%\System32\msxml3.dll,0`) but keep Notepad as the default program?

I downloaded [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) and it shows `%SystemRoot%\System32\msxml3.dll,0` as the default icon for XML files, even though that is not the icon I see in Explorer, and even in FileTypesMan itself!

Comment: Filetypesman can do this....http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12383/change-a-file-types-icon-in-windows-7/

Comment: @Moab Thanks, though I had already edited my question: FileTypesMan reports a different icon than the one that is actually displayed in Explorer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Default Programs Editor** can do what you need:

> Default Programs Editor makes it easy to fix file association settings in Windows, including context menu items, icons, and descriptions.

[image: Screenshot]

- Original Link - http://defaultprogramseditor.com
- Article - http://lifehacker.com/5339059/
- Download Page - http://default-programs-editor.en.softonic.com/

Comment: Your Welcome :)

Comment: Just as a note, this program doesn't actually allow you to change the default program for a filetype without changing the icon. What it ***does*** do is allow you to reset your filetype's icon ***after*** it's been been changed.

Comment: Typically the default icons can be found in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\imageres.dll`

Comment: @MichielvanOosterhout, can you specify the steps that you performed in the program? Thanks